# is there any codeigniter function for verifying payment in ccavenue?

Tags: codeigniter, payment, verify, ccavenue

need to recheck the payments in database that is failed or not in ccavenue using codeigniter

How do we know if payment is successful or not in Indian Ccavenue Payment gateway  i dont know about it. IS there any kinds of code which will helps me to solve out my problem?

codeigniter function for verifying payment in ccavenue

Comment: No, CodeIgniter has no native interaction with any payment systems.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter does not provide any such inbuilt function.
You should use the **'orderStatusTracker'** API provided by CCAvenue to achieve your goal.
[Download API docs & sample](https://links.avenues.info/downloads/API_Document_Sample_Code-New.zip)